# Why QR-decomposition returns transpose of Q?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

In the documentary we read about `QRDecomposition` ([Link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QRDecomposition.html?v=13.2))

> QRDecomposition[m]
> yields the QR decomposition for a numerical matrix m. The result is a list {q,r}, where q is a unitary matrix and r is an upper‐triangular matrix.

By QR-decomposition we can decompose the matrix `m=q.r`. Therefore I was surprised to find following point in the same description:

> The original matrix m is equal to ConjugateTranspose[q].r.

What is the reason that MMA returns the conjugate transpose of q but not q? Because of this reason we can decompose matrix m only by the conjugate transpose of q.

MMA 13.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$q$ is a unitary matrix, so the conjugate transpose is actually the inverse: $q^+=q^{-1}$. In this sense, the equation that is satisfied,

$$
m=q^+\cdot r=q^{-1}\cdot r
$$

can be written as

$$
q\cdot m= r
$$

which is the form of the equation that is, in practice, often very useful. It answers the question: "What do I need to do to $m$ to turn it into a triangular matrix?"

So I guess they picked this latter form when deciding how to deliver the results, for reasons we can ultimately only guess at.

The same remains true for pivoting: `QRDecomposition[m, Pivoting->True]` returns $\{q,r,p\}$ that satisfy

$$
q\cdot m\cdot p=r
$$
and in this sense the matrices $q$ and $p$ serve to turn $m$ into the triangular matrix $r$.